# Understanding bremsstrahlung spectrum in Landau-Lifschitz

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am reading through Landau, Lifschitz "The classical theory of fields", in particular I am reading about bremsstrahlung spectrum in $\S70$ "Radiation in the case of Coulomb interaction".

The book says that the radiation emitted by a single particle is given by:

$$d\mathcal{E}_\omega=\dfrac{\pi \mu^2\alpha^2\omega^3}{6c^3\mathcal{E}^2}\left( \dfrac{e_1}{m_1}-\dfrac{e_2}{m_2} \right)^2\left[ (H^{(1)'}_{i\nu}(i\nu\epsilon))^2- \dfrac{\epsilon^2-1}{\epsilon^2} (H^{(1)}_{i\nu}(i\nu\epsilon))^2\right]d\omega,
\tag{70.18}$$

where $e_i$ and $m_i$ ($i=1,2$) are the particles charges and masses, $\alpha=|e_1e_2|$, $\mu$ is the reduced mass, $\mathcal{E}$ is the energy, $\nu=\dfrac{\omega\alpha}{\mu v^3}$ ($v$ is the relative velocity) and $$\epsilon=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2\mathcal{E}M^2}{\mu \alpha^2}},$$

where $M$ is the angular momentum.

There are two things I do not understand:

1. Is the angular momemtnum $M$ a parameter?
2. I cannot make sense of the unit of measurement in the equation for $d\mathcal{E}_\omega$: for example $\nu$ should be a number but from its definition it is far from being clear.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I've edited your question, fixing two typos in the equation. I suppose they don't affect the core of your question, but I'm notifying you just to be sure. My fixes might be wrong if your edition of LL shows what you had typed instead of the fixed expression.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for th edit; the sign was actually a third problem of mine: I always got a negative function when I tried to plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landau uses Gaussian units (see $\S27$, this is stated right before equation $(27.4)$), in which [the unit of charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Unit_of_charge), the *statcoulomb*, is defined as

$$1\,\mathrm{statC} = 1\,\mathrm{g}^{1/2}\,\mathrm{cm}^{3/2}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}.$$

This, in particular, gives the Coulomb's law in the form

$$F=\frac{e_1e_2}{r^2},$$

without a special constant of proportionality.

With this, all the equations, including $(70.12)$ that defines the semimajor axis as $a=\frac{\alpha}{2\mathcal{E}}$, make sense with the $\alpha$ defined as $\alpha=|e_1e_2|$. And the $\nu$ becomes then simply an angle, which is dimensionless and can be passed to transcendental functions.

As for whether the angular momentum $M$ is a parameter, yes, it is. It's quite usual to "hide" it inside the eccentricity of the orbit when analyzing motions in Coulomb-type fields.